# How to use @AutoConfigureTestDatabase at the application level for spring boot 2.7+

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-test

My Spring-boot application has many `@SpringBootTest` and `@DataJpaTest` test classes.
My application also uses a H2 database.
I want my tests to use the DB defined at the application level.

The annotation with value `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)` works fine. But the problem is, I need to add this configuration to almost 50+ classes. Or else create an abstract class with this annotation and make my tests extend this abstract class which will again result in making changes in 50+ files.

Is there any better way to do it? Like in `application.yml` of the tests? Or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

Making changes to 50 files or even 5000 files shouldn't be a problem, as long as you don't have to touch each by hand.

With a proper IDE it shouldn't be a problem to search and replace `@SpringBootTest` and `DataJpaTest` with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)`.

You probably wan't to include the fully classified class names and then run a "organize imports" on all (touched) files.